# Chrome extension proxy authentication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I've got problem in proxy authentication using chrome extension (due to problems with v3 my code is based on manifest v2). The connection works using the following `curl` command:

`curl -v -x https://11.111.11.111:222 https://www.google.com/ --proxy-header "proxy-authorization: Basic abc" --proxy-insecure`

And I tried to implement it in extension. Here's what I have in `background.js` file:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
    const config = {
            mode: 'fixed_servers',
            rules: {
                singleProxy: {
                    host: '11.111.11.111',
                    port: 222,
                    scheme: 'https',
                },
            },
        }

        chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: 'regular' })
})

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    (details) => {
        const requestHeaders = details.requestHeaders || []
        requestHeaders.push({
            name: 'proxy-authorization',
            value: 'Basic abc',
        })

        return { requestHeaders }
    },
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
    ['blocking', 'requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']
)

chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(
    (details) => {
        console.log('sending', details)
        return details
    },
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
    ['requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']
)
```

I have the following permissions in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "proxy",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
```

And these are the headers that are printed in `onSendHeaders` function:

[image]

You see that `proxy-authorization` header is present. But I get `ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID` while trying to browse any page. Proxy headers should be set in a different way? Because I use `--proxy-header` flag in the curl command, not `--header`.

PS. I tried using the method that is mentioned many times:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details, callbackFn) {
    callbackFn({
        authCredentials: { username: username, password: password }
    });
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},['asyncBlocking']);
```

too, but this function is never called (I put console.log inside).

Comment: Your issue does not seem to be in the authorization, but in the fact that you can't reproduce the behavior of `--proxy-insecure` (since the certificate is not trusted for IP). Is there a specific reason the proxy runs over HTTPS? If it's a proxy you control, can you set up your own cert for the IP and set up OS trust for it?

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this issue? If yes please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is for manifest v3 to add in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestAuthProvider",
]
```

and in `background.js`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details, callbackFn) {
    callbackFn({
        authCredentials: { 
           username: YOUR_USERNAME, 
           password: YOUR_PASSWORD 
        }
    });
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},['asyncBlocking']);
```

This works for me.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this problem?

If not try this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details, callbackFn) {
    callbackFn({
        authCredentials: { username: username, password: password }
    });
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},['blocking']);
```

Main change - **AsyncBlocking** => **Blocking**